# Why are my particle settings grayed out?

Tags: particles

The particle number on my settings appear in gray, I don't think i'm able to change the number even thought i need it, how can i make it white again?

[image]

Comment: Is the particle system linked from a different file? In that case, you have to change the settings there.

Comment: This will happen when you have done something in *particle edit* mode, like combing or adding particles.  If this is the case there will be a *free particle edit* button somewhere.

Comment: No, the particle system is linked normally with the same objects on the same scene/layer in the same file.
Also, i just changed 'grid' to 'random' and it changed back to normal...but then i go back to 'grid' and the settings are still gray, yet i can only change the number of particles in any of the options except in 'Grid'.

Comment: Have you baked the particle system?

Comment: For future reference, the reason that the particle number is grayed out is that the particle layout is set to Grid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found the solution for it: It is greyed out when it was baked. Go to the "cache" section in the particle system and click on "free bake" to be able to edit the greyed out settings again.

Comment: In Blender 3.3 it's "Delete all bakes" in the cache tab